# For loop in html

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I'm writing a html page using Javascript. Some part of my part will send a request and get a number of results. But the number of the results is unknown before.

So how can I create  for each result? In other words, is there a for loop like thing in html? If not, how can I do this?

Some part of my code:

```
function onMessage(evt)
{
  var recv = JSON.parse(evt.data);
  //writeToScreen("response type: " + recv.type + '\n');
}
```

The above part will return a json contains a user list (the number of user is unknown). And I want to create a  for each user in the html.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a `for loop` in javascript

Comment: HTML is a markup language, not a scripting or programming language.

Comment: please share some code that illustrates what you've attempted.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow Already do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, HTML exists for structure and there are no functions like loops. What you are probably looking for is a JavaScript `for` loop, specifically a `for..in` or `while` loop because the number of loops is unknown

You can learn about Javascript `for...in` loops [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), but tldr it could look something like this in your HTML:

`<script type="text/javascript">` and then your loop and a `document.write()`, closed by `</script>`

Edit: Looks like you added a code snippet. Based on that, you should go with Jquery like the other answer suggests

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use JavaScript to create HTML elements for each item in your result. If you don't know [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) I ***highly*** recommend learning that if you're just starting out. Here is a JQuery sample that makes a request to the server, gets back a variable number of results, and creates an element for each item returned.

```
$.ajax({ url: '/my/api/url' }).then(function (response) {
  // I'm assuming your server returned a response that is an array of items.
  response.forEach(function (item) {
    $('<li>').text(item.text).appendTo('ul#myList');
  });
});
```

And then you'd have a `<ul>` element somewhere in your markup with the ID "myList".

```
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```